# django save - database not updating

Tags: django, django-models

I have models with custom save methods.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.body_html = markdown(self.body)
    super(News, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

I can add news nae bother and everything is fine until I decide to alter the data in an existing object.
I make the change and hit save and am told that

> "The news "The best news" was changed successfully."

However, it most certainly was not and the data stays the same as it was before the changes.

What am I forgetting or doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is saving, rather than where you're using it? Is it possible you've cached the old object, or have set it as a global object? How are you getting it from the db to display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is to do with this:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    if not hasattr(instance, "poster"):
        instance.poster = request.user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

in the admin.py.

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.body_html = markdown(self.body)
    super(News, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you remove `save()` override, all works correct?